# C++ design pattern for block diagrams

Tags: c++, design-patterns, architecture

I am working on a application that is designed as a high-level block diagram, similar to Simulink or LabView. Unlike a typical Simulink / LabView program, it does a lot of I/O and data transformations. As this situation is not completely uncommon, I suspect that various solutions may already exist.

In order to find the most suitable approach, I am seeking suggestions for a design pattern in C++. What is the best way to turn a continuously executing block diagram into C++ code?
Would anyone be willing to share their thoughts and experiences, perhaps with a code example?

The following is my own draft code. Both input and output is represented as an `any`object. A block may have an unlimited number of processor functions for different types. They are indexed in a `map` object, which connects the actual input type to the right processor function.

Looks like it does its job, but can it be made simpler, more elegant, and easier to read? I am particularly unhappy with all the casts that I had to make.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

using   std::vector, std::map,
        std::type_info, std::type_index,
        std::any,
        std::cout, std::endl;


class Block {
protected:
    map<type_index, any (Block::*)(any)> processors;

public:
    virtual any process(any in) {
        auto it = processors.find(type_index(in.type()));
        return (this->*it->second)(in);
    }
};

class MultiplyBlock : public Block {
    any multiply(any in_) {
        auto in = std::any_cast<vector<float>>(in_);
        float product{1};
        for (auto f : in) {
            product *= f;
        }
        return product;
    }

public:
    MultiplyBlock() {
        processors.emplace(
                typeid(vector<float>),
                static_cast<any (Block::*)(any)>(&MultiplyBlock::multiply)
        );
    }
};

int main() {
    MultiplyBlock m;
    cout << any_cast<float>(m.process(vector<float>{1, 2, 3})) << endl;
}
```

PS:

Per comment from @463035818_is_not_a_number, I'm adding a more expansive example that deals with more than one data type. The point is that I am looking for a design pattern that can be used to deal with any kind of inputs and outputs.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_set>

#include <typeinfo>
#include <typeindex>

#include <any>
#include <iostream>

using   std::vector, std::map, std::unordered_set,
        std::type_info, std::type_index,
        std::any, std::byte,
        std::cout, std::endl;

class Block {
protected:
    map<type_index, any (Block::*)(any)> processors;

public:
    virtual any process(any in) {
        auto it = processors.find(in.type());
        return (this->*it->second)(in);
    }
};

class MultiplyBlock : public Block {
    any multiply(any in_) {
        auto in = any_cast<vector<float>>(in_);
        float product{1};
        for (auto f : in) {
            product *= f;
        }
        return product;
    }

public:
    MultiplyBlock() {
        processors.emplace(
            typeid(vector<float>),
            static_cast<any (Block::*)(any)>(&MultiplyBlock::multiply));
    }
};

class InterpretDataBlock : public Block {
    byte magic_byte;
    any interpret(any in_) {
        auto in = any_cast<unordered_set<byte>>(in_);
        if (in.contains(magic_byte))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

   public:
    InterpretDataBlock(byte magic_byte) : magic_byte(magic_byte) {
        processors.emplace(
            typeid(unordered_set<byte>),
            static_cast<any (Block::*)(any)>(&InterpretDataBlock::interpret));
    }
};

int main() {
    MultiplyBlock m;
    cout << any_cast<float>(m.process(vector<float>{1, 2, 3})) << endl;
    InterpretDataBlock i(byte{'Q'});
    unordered_set<byte> s{byte{0}, byte{1}, byte{'Q'}};
    cout << any_cast<bool>(i.process(s)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I wouldnt use `any`. I don't know simulink, in labview ins and outs have a type iirc, and you can only connect those with matching type. I dont see the advantage of using `any`, especially as then you use `float` for the result of multiplcation anyhow

Comment: In our use case, the input can be an arbitrary type, not just float. We can have blocks that need to deal with for example byte arrays, strings or custom data types.

Comment: but `product *= f;` does not deal with any of that when `product` is a `float`. Also you declared return type of `multiply` to be `any`, but then always return a `float`

Comment: This design pattern need to be open to blocks with other data types. I edited my question to expand it with a block that handles a different data type. I hope this clarifies why I decided to use ```any```, although I of course welcome all ideas for a more elegant solution.

Comment: the question is whether you have a block that needs to deal with `any` or if each block only works with specific types? Your first example was a block that only works with `float`, now you added one that only works with `unordered_set<byte>`. I understand that you need to glue them somehow, but from a blocks perspective there is no need for `any`. They take certain input to produce certain output, right?

Comment: I want blocks to have a uniform interface. So want to be able to call `Block::process(some_data)`, and have the block figure out what to do with the data depending on its type.

Comment: but if `some_data` is from output of a previous block then, it is of some specific type, no? I mean you need type erasure somewhere thats clear. Just consider that "uniform interface" does not need to be as strict as you may be used from eg polymorphism. All blocks having some `OutputType process(const InputType&)` method is already a "uniform interface" even if `OutputType` and `InputType` is different for each block. Btw sorry for long discussion. I think I understood what you want by now.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that each block only works with a specific type. A block does not need the `any` type, which is why it converts it to whichever type it supports. The output to the next block (`some_data`) is always of a specific type. Thank you for asking these questions, they already helped me to better understand my requirements.

Comment: what is left to clarify is what do you want to do at compile time and what do you want to do at runtime. Do you want to be able to link to blocks at runtime? In your code example its all in the code, known at compile time already

Comment: That's a good question. It would be nice if we didn't have to recompile every time the block diagram changed. Could the block diagram be specified in e.g. an XML file?